# Copying files from adb to window

Tags: android, adb

Is there any way to copy files from the adb shell to another place in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in your `DDMS` Perspective and in `File Explorer`, located the file, click `Pull out file` icon and save it where you want...

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad question as you could have this answered by simply reading the [adb manual page](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html). You are looking for `adb pull`

Comment: Well none of my searches led me to this page, but I guess you're right.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Everything regarding the tools from the sdk, you should first check the official android developer page. It is better than most official project pages...